# videojs - Can someone please provide me with instructions to remove the full screen button

Tags: video.js

video.js - hello, newbie here, and i'm hoping someone could tell me what code i would need to place in the video-js.css file so that the full screen button does not show ?

have tried some codes I found online, but the button still shows in all browsers.

fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

In your css look for the block of CSS marked:

`.vjs-fullscreen-control { ... }`

or

`.vjs-default-skin .vjs-fullscreen-control { ... }`

Within that block add `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

instead of `display:none;` you can use `visibility:hidden;`
the advantage is that the width of your tool bar remain the same and is correctly displayed.